# Is there a "Pythonic" way of creating a list with conditional items?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've got this block of code in a real Django function. If certain conditions are met, items are added to the `list`.

```
ret = []

if self.taken():
    ret.append('taken')

if self.suggested():
    ret.append('suggested')

#.... many more conditions and appends...

return ret
```

It's very *functional*. You know what it does, and that's great...
But I've learned to appreciate the beauty of `list` and `dict` comprehensions.

Is there a more *Pythonic* way of phrasing this construct, perhaps that initialises and populates the array in one blow?

Answer (score 3):

Create a mapping dictionary:

```
self.map_dict = {'taken': self.taken,
                 'suggested': self.suggested,
                 'foo' : self.bar}
[x for x in ['taken', 'suggested', 'foo'] if self.map_dict.get(x, lambda:False)()]
```

---

Related: [Most efficient way of making an if-elif-elif-else statement when the else is done the most?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166074/most-efficient-way-of-making-an-if-elif-elif-else-statement-when-the-else-is-don)

Answer (score 2):

Not a big improvement, but I'll mention it:

```
def populate():
    if self.taken():
        yield 'taken'
    if self.suggested():
        yield 'suggested'

ret = list(populate())
```

Can we do better? I'm skeptical. Clearly there's a need of using another syntax than a list literal, because we no longer have the "1 expression = 1 element in result" invariant.

---

Edit:

There's a pattern to our data, and it's a list of (condition, value) pairs. We might try to exploit it using:

```
[value
 for condition, value
 in [(self.taken(), 'taken'),
     (self.suggested(), 'suggested')]
 if condition]
```

but this still is a restriction for how you describe your logic, still has the nasty side effect of evaluating all values no matter the condition (unless you throw in a ton of lambdas), and I can't really see it as an improvement over what we've started with.

Answer (score 1):

For this *very specific* example, I could do:

```
return [x for x in ['taken', 'suggested', ...] if getattr(self, x)()]
```

But again, this *only*  works where the item and method it calls to check have the same name, ie for my exact code. It could be adapted but it's a bit crusty. I'm very open to other solutions!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why we are appending strings that match the function names, but if this is a general pattern, we can use that.  Functions have a `__name__` attribute and I think it always contains what you want in the list.

So how about:

```
return [fn.__name__ for fn in (self.taken, self.suggested, foo, bar, baz) if fn()]
```

If I understand the problem correctly, this works just as well for non-member functions as for member functions.

EDIT:

Okay, let's add a mapping dictionary.  And split out the function names into a tuple or list.

```
fns_to_check = (self.taken, self.suggested, foo, bar, baz)

# This holds only the exceptions; if a function isn't in here,
# we will use the .__name__ attribute.
fn_name_map = {foo:'alternate', bar:'other'}

def fn_name(fn):
    """Return name from exceptions map, or .__name__ if not in map"""
    return fn_name_map.get(fn, fn.__name__)

return [fn_name(fn) for fn in fns_to_check if fn()]
```

You could also just use @hcwhsa's mapping dictionary answer.  The main difference here is I'm suggesting just mapping the exceptions.

Comment: not always, names can be overriden by poorly designed decorators

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have a "sentinel"-style object to take the place of list entries that fail the corresponding condition.  Then a function can be defined to [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) out the missing items:

```py
# "sentinel indicating a list element that should be skipped
Skip = object()

def drop_missing(itr):
    """returns an iterator yielding all but Skip objects from the given itr"""
    return filter(lambda v: v is not Skip, itr)
```

With this simple machinery, we come reasonably close to list-comprehension style syntax:

```py
return drop_skips([
    'taken' if self.taken else Skip,
    'suggested' if self.suggested else Skip,
    100 if self.full else Skip,
    // many other values and conditions
])
```

Answer (score 0):

In another instance (where a value will be defined but might be None - a Django model's fields in my case), I've found that just adding them and filtering works:

```
return filter(None, [self.user, self.partner])
```

If either of those is `None`, They'll be removed from the list. It's a little more intensive than just checking but still fairly easy way of cleaning the output without writing a book.

Answer (score 0):

```
ret = [
    *('taken' for _i in range(1) if self.taken()),
    *('suggested' for _i in range(1) if self.suggested()),    
]
```

The idea is to use the list comprehension syntax to construct either a single element list with item 'taken', if self.taken() is True, or an empty list, if self.taken() is False, and then unpack it.

Comment: @greybeard It's just to use list comprehension to construct a list with at most one element