# How can I make a long if else and strings generic?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, string-formatting

I have a value_list which is created generic and this value_list includes something like this:

```
['C','E','F'] # this always changes
```

Now I have to write into a file which of these rules where attached in value_list.

I saved all my rules in all rules.

```
all_rules = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'] #this can also change so thats why i have to do it generic
```

First I did something like this and this works but I want to do it generic:

```
marked_rule = ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]

        for value in value_list:
            if value == "A":
                marked_rule [0] = "X"
            elif value == "B":
                marked_rule [1] = "X"
            elif value == "C":
                marked_rule [2] = "X"
            elif value == "D":
                marked_rule [3] = "X"
            elif value == "E":
                marked_rule [4] = "X"
            elif value == "F":
                marked_rule [5] = "X"

new_line= "{:-<1} {:-<1} {:-<1} {:-<1} {:-<1} {:-<1}".format(*marked_rule)
```

Here it write into file

Output:

```
A B C D E F  
- - X - X X #marked_rule should look like this ["-" "-" "X" "-" "X" "X"].
```

**TODO: make it generic:**

first I want to do these lines as often as my all_rules  list is

```
marked_rule = ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
```

Next I want to add without writing these hard coded If clauses

Frist try, but does not work:

```
        for index, value in enumerate (value_list):
            if value == all_rules [index]:
                marked_rule[index] = "X"
```

Next also want to do the string formatting generic, so it shoud contain so many `{:-<1}` as much as the index of all_rules. The problem is I add somethig before and after (these are fix) . In real case it looks like this:

```
" *  {:<10} {:-<1} {:-<1} {:-<1} {:-<1} {:-<1} {:-<1} {:<23} {:<3}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way of making an if-elif-elif-else statement when the else is done the most?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166074/most-efficient-way-of-making-an-if-elif-elif-else-statement-when-the-else-is-don)

Comment: I have seen this post before, but I have a different case. I coulndt solve it. Could you maybe help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `list`-comprehension combined with ternary `if` for that task i.e.:

```
rules = ['C','E','F']
all_rules = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
marked_rule = ['X' if i in rules else '-' for i in all_rules]
print(marked_rule)
```

Output:

```
['-', '-', 'X', '-', 'X', 'X']
```

Then use `.join` to get string out of it - this will work with any number of arguments:

```
output = ' '.join(marked_rule)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
- - X - X X
```